# Duplicate Region Name in AWS client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After installing the MSI 62bit package from [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html) (with the default options) and typing `aws --version` to confirm the installation, when I type `aws configure` I get the following:

```
C:\Users\Usuario>aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.37 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.8.41


Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.16299.192]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\Usuario>aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************skey]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************tkey]:
Default region name [Default region name [None]:]:
Default output format [None]:

C:\Users\Usuario>
```

The default region name is duplicated and does not function. It works in another computer with the same procedure.

¿Any help?

I use windows 10.0.16299.192 and I have installed Anaconda 64bit (Python 3.6.3).

The desired output should be:

```
C:\Users\Usuario>aws configure
    AWS Access Key ID [****************skey]:
    AWS Secret Access Key [****************tkey]:
    Default region name [None]:
    Default output format [None]:
```

**EDIT 13/02/2018**

Thanks @Michael - sqlbot for the clue. I have just manage to do it.

I have delete the whole .aws folder and reinstall the MSI installer. Once done that, the duplicate does not appear anymore.

Comment: Find your [configuration file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html) and examine its contents.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot,

Just found it. There is the following inside. What do I have to delete?

[default]
region = hyrhtreyhre
region = [eu-west-2]
region = Default region name [None]: